# Javascript function submits multiple requests to database

Tags: javascript, java

I have the below javascript function called whenever the user presses the PRINT ALL button , this inturn calls my java code and start printing the list for the user. For some reason i am seeing multiple calls are submitted to my java code which creates empty entries in database even though the user the PRINT ALL button only once.

```
function printAll(){
  with(document.forms.printPending){
    print_nums.value="all_new";
    submit();
}   
}
```

Can anyone explain me how to avoid multiple calls to the java code from the javascript function ?.

Comment: If you are submitting a form using a custom function, make sure that you disable the default behavior.

Comment: Also, are you sure there aren't multiple click events bound to the button which may cause multiple calls?

Comment: Your button may be set as a submit button

Comment: *Please* avoid using `with`. It makes it hard to understand even such a short snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a global variable that counts the amount of clicks? if > 1 don't run. Not the best solution, but quick fix